# How do you extract till the second last element from each sub-list in a nested list?

Tags: python

How do you extract till the second last element from each sub-list in a nested list?

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [1, 3, 5, 6, 8]]
```

The desired output is:

```
y = [[1, 2], [4], [7, 8], [1, 3, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following method to do this:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9], [1, 3, 5, 6, 8]]
y = [sublist[:-1] for sublist in x]
```

output:

```
[[1, 2], [4], [7, 8], [1, 3, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
y = [ar[:-1] for ar in x]
```